# Перенос папок  в папку

Tags: файлы, php

Есть папка A
Есть папка Б

Нужно перенести содержимое Б в А. Содержимое может совпадать по имени.
Т.е. если совпали папки, то просто переносится содержимое папки, если совпали файлы, то перезаписываются. Если папки нет, то создается и переносятся данные. [Здесь](forum.dklab.ru/php/advises/FileFunctions.html) очень похожая функция, но не работает с совпадениями. Думаю многие встречались с подобным.

p.s. как запасной план, использовать линуксовые возможности.

Comment: Т.е. простая процедура слияния папок и файлов

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Создается функция которая принимает на вход путь и создаёт папки для этого пути. (например, mkdirs('/home/pupkin/dirs/A'); на каждой папке проверяет её существование, если папки не существует - то создаём её если существует то ничего не делаем, переходим к вледующей части пути)
2. Создаётся функция рекурсивного копирования.

   recursiveCopy($from, $to)

читаем содержимое папки $from в цикле:

```
    если это файл то: копируем его из $from.'/'.$file в $to.'/'.$file
    если это папка: mkdirs($to.'/'.$file); recursiveCopy($from.'/'.$file, $to.'/'.$file);
```

вот и всё.

Comment: Спасибо. Примерно понял. Вроде не сложно, буду пробовать

Answer (score 1):

Вот, готовый код. `$from` - откуда копируем, `$to` - куда. Пути задавать полные (ну по крайне мере у меня работает так, если `$from/$to = '../from/'/'../to/'`)

Одно, что папки `from` и `to` должны быть указаны, остальные папки, которые есть в папке `from`, в `to` создаются сами, удачной работы))

```
 function recursiveCopy($from, $to){
        if(!file_exists($to)){
            mkdir($to);
            }
       if ($objs = glob($from."/*")) {
           foreach($objs as $obj) {
              $forto=$to.str_replace($from, '', $obj);
             // echo $to.'<br>';
               if(is_dir($obj)){
                   removeDirRec($obj, $forto);
                   }
                else{
                    copy($obj, $forto);
                    }
           }
       }
       return true;
    }
```

---